# How to update a tuple with a function taking a tuple a parameter in Swift UiKit

Tags: swift

I want to use a tuple to store some values. I also would like to be able to update the elements of the tuple using a function.

I believe in this case, using a Struct could work but I find it quicker to use a tuple.

I found how to pass a tuple to the function as a parameter but when I want to update an element of the tuple with the function I get an error: "Cannot assign to property: 'targetMacro' is a 'let' constant" - the idea (see my code below) would be to pass fatParams as an argument and update it's units element.

Any idea why that is and how to use a function to update a tuple's element?

Thank you!

```
var fatParams = (units: "g", amount: "")
    
func setUnits (tappedButton: UIButton, targetMacro: (units: String, amount: String)) {
    targetMacro.units = tappedButton.currentTitle!
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptvq7.png)

I tried to use self (self.targetMarco.unist) but that's not the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `inout` to make the parameter mutable

```
func setUnits (tappedButton: UIButton, targetMacro: inout (units: String, amount: String)) {
    targetMacro.units = tappedButton.currentTitle!
}

setUnits(tappedButton: someButton, targetMacro: &fatParams)
```

Or you can let the function return a new version of the tuple

```
func setUnits(tappedButton: UIButton, targetMacro: (units: String, amount: String)) -> (String, String) {
    return (tappedButton.currentTitle!, targetMacro.amount)
}

fatParams = setUnits(tappedButton: someButton, targetMacro: fatParams)
```